# I can't delete a Table of Contents in Word for Mac. The remove does delete the table, but it keeps returning. I need to make a new TOC

Tags: mac, microsoft-word, table-of-contents, microsoft

I have a long document with a TOC. After editing the document several times, I want to create a new table of contents. I have removed the old one several times, to no avail. The old TOC returns each time I've tried to create a new one. How can I delete the old TOC permanently?

Answer (score 1):

### Toggle the display of field codes. (Opt+F9) Then delete the *TOC Field*

A Table of Contents, in a Word document, is a TOC *field*. You can toggle display of such codes and manipulate them directly.

***On some computers, the keyboard shortcut is Fn+Opt+F9.***

Remember to toggle back to display of field results after you delete  the field.

Here is [my article on dealing with fields](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/dealing-with-fields-in-microsoft-word/e1bdddad-5a51-4327-837c-c3786c16a501) on the Microsoft website.

Comment: I TRIED YOUR SUGGESTION. I THINK IT DID THE TRICK. THANKS

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers